# C# Application over a Network

Tags: c#, deployment, networking

I have run into a few cases where i have been asked to deploy an application (C#, .Net 2.0) to a server and users need to test the application over the network. I have found the following that works with out any hitches other than a warning telling you "hey your running this over a network are you sure you want to do this?":

```
%systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\caspol -m -cg 1.2 -url \\<Path> FullTrust
```

Is there a better way of centralizing the application than the above?

Comment: Why is the asp.net-2.0 tag there? Is this a winforms/wpf/console app?

Comment: Sorry about that. The .net 2.0 tag was there because the command line string above is set for the path to that directory and that's the run time the app is in. sorry about the wrong tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with granting FullTrust, is that [it really really means *full* trust](http://blogs.msdn.com/eugene_bobukh/archive/2005/05/06/415217.aspx). If your app has any sort of identity/security control, the granting fulltrust will bypass all of that.

I guess otherwise, you're "exposing" your machine to files running from that other one, so they could potentially do damage, however this is no worse than any other native win32 executable running on a remote machine, so it's no big deal IMHO.

I'd recommend the best solution is to simply install the app on your user's machines. You could use something like ClickOnce to make this painless and easy for them.

Comment: Good point about the full trust, but it seems like this is running from inside some sort of trusted network where (presumably) malicious software isn't going to be posted.

Comment: yeah, it's more about if the app needs to be designed to work in a partial trust environment, or similar, then granting FullTrust will bypass that kind of check

Answer (score 6):

Try using [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) deployment.  We use it for all of our network-deployed applications.

Comment: Your link may be a better one, though.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504585/c-application-over-a-network/504602#504602

Comment: Nice solution. A few of the users have very limited permissions to install on there computers ill have to look into what kind of workarounds they may need.

Comment: This seams to be the most recommended application for deployment. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Best solution would probably be to sign your assemblies, and push out a full-trust policy to all of the client machines for those assemblies. Then, just run them from the network share via the UNC path as if they were local.

Comment: I disagree with this solution, but I'm not gonna downmod you for it. ClickOnce is the best way to handle deployment scenarios of this sort, IMO.

Comment: Normally I'd agree (that was my first thought as well), but we're not necessarily talking about something that needs to be deployed. Also, there could be technical reasons (or policies) in the way of setting up a web server for this.

Comment: @DannySmurf: Very good point as i said above there are limited permissions hence the way we have done it for now. So far i accept both answers.

Answer (score 1):

You might look into [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx) deployment. Usually a much better way to deploy than running on a share.